# Prometheus query and case sensitivity

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, promql

I have one query where I am trying to join two metrics on a label.
K_Status_Value == 5 and ON(macAddr) state_details{live="True"}

The label macAddr is present in both the metrics. The value of the label appears in 'K_Status_Value' sometimes in upper case (78:32:5A:29:2F:0D) and sometimes in lower case (78:72:5d:39:2f:0a) but always appears in upper case for 'state_details'. Is there any way I can make the label macAddr value case-insensitive in the query so that I don't miss out on the occurrences where the cases don't match?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I can think of two options

## Using regex "i" match modifier:

To quote Ben Kochie on Prometheus user [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/prometheus-users/xOeIocdR_hI):

> The regexp matching in Prometheus is based on [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)
> I think you can set flags within a match by using `(?i(matchstring))`

It works indeed: this metric `up{instance="localhost:9090",job="prometheus"}` is matched by this expression :

```
up{job=~"(?i:(ProMeTHeUs))"}
```

This hint won't help in the case described above. It won't help either to join `on (xx)` or `group_left`.

## Using a recording rule:

I was initialy hoping to use a [recording rule](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/rules/) to lower case at ingestion time (in `prometheus.yml`). However this features is not implemented at this time ([issue 1548](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/1548))

Answer (score -3):

It looks like Prometheus has no functionality for matching label values in different cases :( But this can be solved with [label_uppercase](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_uppercase) and/or [label_lowercase](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_lowercase) functions from [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html). For example, the following query should properly match `macAddr` label values in different cases:

```
(label_lowercase(K_Status_Value, "macAddr") == 5)
and ON(macAddr)
label_lowercase(state_details{live="True"}, "macAddr")
```

Comment: This fonction is specific to VicroriaMetrics, not a prometheus/PromQL solution.